# Get List item version history into Keyword Query Language Search Result

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, kql

I am using search KQL to show the data within my custom visual web part. I googled for many hours but could not find anything related to List Item version history within search query. Is it possible to get Version History using search KQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, the crawler only indexes the tip revision of the current item. Previous versions are not indexed. In the past I have done this by using the current item from the search result and then using javascript to fetch the versions of the item.

Comment: Thanks Mattew for confirmation. I experience same behavior.